# How can I highlight words on my page for which the user has googled?

Tags: google-search

I noticed that certain web pages do highlight the words I googled for.

**Example:** Try [searching for "virtualbox"](http://google.com/search?q=virtualbox) and go to the VirtualBox page. Now "virtualbox" is highlighted on that page.

I want to do the same on my page. How can I know the words the user was searching for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You check [referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) and parse out the words. Most likely there will even be javascript functions for doing that.

Comment: Here's couple of those javascript functions Rashack mentioned http://eriwen.com/javascript/highlight-search-results-with-js/ and http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/searchhi/